# How to create a solid stream of liquid?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

[image: Currently what I have right now]

I'm new to blender and I want to create more things with the fluid simulation but it's not coming out like a faucet, instead it comes out in these globs is there a way to change this?

P.S: I also noticed that whenever I increase the resolution of the final the amount of liquid that comes out of the inflow decreases is there also a way to fix this?

Comment: The resolution is too low. You could either scale up the inflow object or increase the resolution of the simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your inflow Mesh is just a circle?
I think you maybe should use a Sphere. Another Way to achieve more water is to increase the "inicial Velocity" of your Inflow Object.